# How to update the string inside the PLIST

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have Array of the 40 item and inside that dict.Dict contain the 2 string item, i want to write the string item to 0 to 1 when user click on uibutton

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>quote</key>
        <string>Some Quotes</string>
        <key>favorite</key>
        <string>0</string>
    </dict>

</array>
```

I am applying following code but it doesn`t work for me ...

```
-(void) addFavorite
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");

    [someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_favoritegold.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    NSURL *documents = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *plistUrl = [documents URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"quotes.plist"];
    NSArray *plistContents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistUrl];
    NSMutableDictionary *editFavorite = [plistContents objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

it does not change the favorite 0 to 1 and my plist is in the supporting file do i have to make any changes in property list .

Comment: Can you show me the data of your .plist file ?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit ?

Comment: Where is your .plist reside means in DocumentDirectory or in Cache ?

Comment: @Bhupendra You can not update the plist that resides in resource bundle, you need to either create on in Applications document directory or copy it from bundle to document directory.

Comment: @BharatJagtap sry I am new to iphone so i have seen one tutorial in which that plist is put in the resource . So how can i put my existing   plist to document directory

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)btnClicked
{
    [arr_Data addObject:str1];
    [arr_Data addObject:str2];

    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   // get documents path
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   // get the path to our Data/plist file
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

   // This writes the array to a plist file. If this file does not already exist, it creates a new one.
   [arr_Data writeToFile:path atomically: TRUE];
}
```

Comment: How to  update particular string in dictionary. do  you have any idea

Comment: Copy your dictionary item in an NSMutableArray and use objectAtIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code for your concept

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
      NSString  *plistdocumentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NsString * plistFilePath = [plistdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"filename.plist"]];
  NSMutableArray  *savedStock = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
     [[savedStock objectAtIndex:indexForWheretoStoreData] setObject:@"your value" forKey:@"your key"];
  [savedStock writeToFile:filePath  atomically:YES];
```

Comment: i am having my plist in supporting file. its is not changing in that file is any change i have to do in that. as bharat says that You can not update the plist that resides in resource bundle, you need to either create on in Applications document directory or copy it from bundle to document directory.

Comment: yes if file in main bundle mean you can't change so copy file into document folder

Comment: so i have to create document folder.because in my project it is not available so how to add it . I did not know because i am new in iphone strated working since 5 or 6 day

Comment: k,in above coding the first two line are used to get document folder in iOS

Comment: in iOS if u run any project ,it automatically create document folder,temp and directory folders,it will present in iPhone simulator folder in system

Comment: But i am using vmware mac , is document folder in project or elsewhere ? can you please justify

Answer (score 0):

**It's a simple 4 Step Process :**

**1)** Select the Dictionary (you want to update the "favorite" tag).

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlist.plist"];
```

**2)** Set New Value.

```
[yourDict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"favorite"];
```

**3)** Insert it to the Array.

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[yourArray addObject:yourDict];
```

**4)** Write that array to **yourPath**.

```
[yourArray writeToURL:yourPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: i want to add particular item`s favorite when user click on that i have index of that item so how can i write the favorite or update the favorite 0 to 1

Comment: But how it can figure what favorite string of particular item has to update..Sry becuase i am new to iphone that why i asked

Comment: Central Idea is that you have to select the Dictionary (you want to update the "favorite" tag), set the new Value , insert it to the Array and write that array to yourPath.

Comment: so can you please tell me how can i select particular dictionary base on the particular item

Answer (score 0):

use `[yourArray writeToURL:yourPath atomically:YES];`to store data

Comment: Do you have whole code snippets to show how to update string inside the dictionary